Any effective pruning or optimization tools for neural networks?
I have been trying to prune a simple neural network model I created using Tensorflow in Python. So far, I am facing problems where I cannot get prune_low_magnitude to work. As a backup, I also built the same model using Pytorch and I was able to prune it using torch.nn.utils.prune. However, I found out that it does not actually "prune" the weights, rather it applies a mask on the network that zeroes out the weights according to the threshold I define. I can see that the sparsity is affected. But, the number of parameters remain the same and I cannot fine-tune the "pruned" model and test it to analyze its performance against the original unpruned network.
My question is: Knowing that torch.nn.utils.prune only applies a mask to increase the sparsity, even if for observation only, is there a way I can achieve my goal of pruning the network and comparing its performance to my original network, be it in Tensorflow or Pytorch?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!
